# Array.find with Array.map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have two arrays, in the first one I store some user data. In the second, I store the basic data about the users.

```
const usersData = [{ userId: 1, age: 18 }];
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Alex'}];
```

I wrote some simple code below:

```
const result = usersData.map(userData => {
    return {
        ...userData,
        userName: users.find(user => user.id === userData.userId).name
    }
})
```

After that, I get the result:

```
const result = [{ userId: 1, age: 18, name: "Alex" }];
```

The question is: how can you write this solution in a simpler way? Maybe should use the library "Lodash"?

---

**Sorry, my English is not so good.**

Comment: What needs to be simpler?

Comment: this line: userName: users.find(user => user.id === userData.userId).name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger datasets, it's better to use a different data structure to increase the performance of the lookup and reduce the runtime.

```js
const usersData = [{ userId: 1, age: 18 }];
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Alex'}];
const usersById = Object.fromEntries(users.map(user => ([user.id, user])));

const result = usersData.map(userData => {
    return {
        ...userData,
        userName: usersById[userData.userId]?.name
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing simpler than this way, but you can optimise it so that you don't have to use `find` for every key. For that you can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here.

**`Note: If are trying to use any library, then under the hood they might be using the same method`**

```js
const usersData = [{ userId: 1, age: 18 }];
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Alex'}];

const usersDict = new Map();  // dictionary for users
users.forEach(o => usersDict.set(o.id, o));

const result = usersData.map(user => ({ ...user, username: usersDict.get(user.userId)?.name}))

console.log(result);
```